# Where do I set socks5 proxy settings on a server?

Tags: server, proxy

Which software is used to setup connection to socks5 proxy from Ubuntu server?

Comment: possible dup of http://askubuntu.com/questions/15719/where-do-i-set-system-wide-proxy-settings

Comment: I suggest it is not a dup because "server" probably means no unity gui. I'd love to see the same answer for a non gui as 15719 question

Answer (score 1):

Besides firefox socks5-client setup (which is what I use most in combination with ssh) I know of dante-client

http://www.inet.no/dante/doc/latest/config/client.html

This package provides the "socksify" client program - a tool which
 forwards network requests from any program to a SOCKS server (v4 or v5)
 which then performs them on your behalf.

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score -2):

Read here-
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-configure-ubuntu-desktop-to-use-your-proxy-server.html

It's a little out of date, but it should give you an idea about what needs to be done.

Try the ubuntu configuration first and see if other utilities are able to derive those settings. If not, configure them separately.