# How do I set a system wide proxy with a username and password?

Tags: proxy

I'm trying to set a system wide proxy, and I'm specifically having difficulties with apt-get for installing applications on my Ubuntu. I'm in a university using a proxy server with username/password. I'm aware of setting a proxy with username and password in the following manner:

http://username:password@proxy.thing.com:8080/

But it fails, as a critical example  with apt-get.  Username contains backslash( \ ) in it and I'm wondering whether that could be a problem for failing. I'd be grateful with any input on this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try escaping the backslash like this:

http://user%5Cname:password@proxy.thing.com:8080/

where '%5C' is the URL-encoded value for the backslash character. See [this background.](http://blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)

Answer (score 8):

Historically, you could set up a proxy using environment variables like
`http_proxy=http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXYIP:PROXYPORT`

So it might be possible to specify the username and password in the host field of the Network section like above, i.e.
`myuser:mypass@my.proxy.com`

Answer (score 2):

1. Open `Network` by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and typing the same.
2. You should clearly see the `Network Proxy` tab.
3. After selecting the tab, select the `Method` to be `manual` and set all the proxies.
4. Then, click `Apply system wide`, it will ask for your password, and you're done.