# system-wide proxy with username/password 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, password, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set a system wide proxy with a username and password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82880/how-do-i-set-a-system-wide-proxy-with-a-username-and-password)

How do I set a system-wide proxy with username/password in Ubuntu 12.04?
I have seen in the 'Network' section of System Settings that I can define the proxy, but I can't see any menu where to set up the username/password combination for the proxy.

Any ideas?