# Proxy does not work using sudo

Tags: 14.04, proxy

I set the proxy using system setting -> Network -> Network Proxy. I then clicked on "Apply system wide", put my password, and nothing else.

```
michele@rserver-VirtualBox:~$ wget http://bbc.co.uk
--2014-09-30 13:02:20--  http://bbc.co.uk/
Resolving datapx01-wcg (datapx01-wcg)... 10.123.7.31
Connecting to datapx01-wcg (datapx01-wcg)|10.123.7.31|:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.bbc.co.uk/ [following]
--2014-09-30 13:02:21--  http://www.bbc.co.uk/
Reusing existing connection to datapx01-wcg:8080.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 103020 (101K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

100%[======================================>] 103,020      190KB/s   in 0.5s   

2014-09-30 13:02:21 (190 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [103020/103020]
```

Instead using sudo:

```
michele@rserver-VirtualBox:~$ sudo wget http://bbc.co.uk
[sudo] password for michele: 
--2014-09-30 13:02:30--  http://bbc.co.uk/
Resolving bbc.co.uk (bbc.co.uk)... 212.58.246.104, 212.58.244.20, 212.58.246.103, ...
Connecting to bbc.co.uk (bbc.co.uk)|212.58.246.104|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
```

I am on 14.04 and I didn't have this issue before upgrading from 12.04 yesterday. Please tell me what other info you need.

Comment: Why do you want to use `sudo` here while it works well without that?

Comment: Check your `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file and see if your proxy setting is also appear there.

Comment: that is simply a reproducible example... my server runs application on behalf of different users, so I need the proxy to work for all users.

Comment: To workaround, use it like this: `sudo env HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:port wget http://bbc.co.uk`.

Comment: Did you try @the_Seppi's suggestion? When you run sudo, environment is restricted.

Comment: @Letizia yes, it did not work

Comment: Did you try to configure and uncomment http_proxy in `/etc/wgetrc` file?

Comment: You need to make some changes in your /etc/sudoers file. Take a look at this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2199416.

Answer (score 13):

In case anybody wonders:

The issue here, is that when sudoing, a newenvironment is loaded, meaning that http_proxy is no longer set.

To resolve this issue you can add `Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy"` to your /etc/sudoers file in order to keep those variables when switching to the secure path.

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: super answer!! worked in CentOS 7 as well.

Comment: Just a note: this would still requires the respective environment variables to be set inside the profile of the user, who belongs to the sudoers. Add `export http_proxy=...` and `export https_proxy=...` to `.bashrc` or whatever your user's profile file is called. Also I recommend putting `no_proxy`, which is quite common for company networks, where internal network locations (e.g. intranet web portal) often not only do not require but will not work if going through proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Open `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file in Terminal and set your proxy setting as following:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:pass@host:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://user:pass@host:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://user:pass@host:port/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://user:pass@host:port/";
```

Replace `user` with your *username*, `pass` with your *password*, `host` with *proxy-webaddress* and `port` with a *portnumber*.

Comment: Those 4 lines are already there. But without the username and password. I ll try adding them

Comment: Just did, still the same

Comment: @Michele run `echo $http_proxy` in terminal did you see the your user and pass and other configure?

Comment: I just get the `http://proxy:port/`

Comment: @Michele then your user and pass not set correctly!!

Comment: triple checked they are fine

Comment: did you restart the system

Comment: No, I thought it was a Windows thing... :-) I'll try now

Comment: Nada... still the same. I just read that sudo does a reset of the environment variables and things like http_proxy don't get used

Comment: @Michele Sorry but I don't have any idea check here http://askubuntu.com/questions/175172/how-do-i-configure-proxies-in-ubuntu-server-or-minimal-cli-ubuntu and here http://askubuntu.com/questions/15719/where-are-the-system-wide-proxy-server-settings and also here http://askubuntu.com/questions/82880/how-do-i-set-a-system-wide-proxy-with-a-username-and-password