# How do I set a system-wide proxy in Lubuntu (or LXDE)?

Tags: networking, lubuntu, proxy, lxde

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set systemwide proxy servers in Xubuntu, Lubuntu or Ubuntu Studio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio)

In Ubuntu with Unity, we have an option to set a system wide proxy. When I tried Lubuntu 12.04, I found no such option.

How do I set a system-wide proxy for Lubuntu?

Graphical method to set system-wide proxy, with screenshots requested.

Comment: hmm - that Q is for unity & gnome - other DEs are different.  You could use `lxproxy` for the GUI but this seems only to write out values to ~/.profile so its not "system wide"