# How do I make a proxy server?

Tags: server, internet, security, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the system-wide proxy server settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15719/where-are-the-system-wide-proxy-server-settings)

How do I make a proxy server that allows other computers to access my internet connection through the proxy, but will not allow them to access my internet connection directly?

I have a server and a switch.  I would also like to provide wifi access under the same conditions.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this question? - [Where are the system wide proxy server settings?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15719/where-are-the-system-wide-proxy-server-settings)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fine project.
http://www.squid-cache.org/

Also, looks like you might use also ipcop that resolve that wireless access in a secure way.
http://www.ipcop.org/

Comment: I guess I am still wondering how I block access to the internet... Let me clarify.  What is to stop someone from using the internet without using my proxy?