# Unable to fetch deb file: connection refused

Tags: apt, connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

I was trying to install emacs and I got a bunch of errors like this:

```
Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/emacsen-common/emacsen-common_1.4.22ubuntu1_all.deb  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8118 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
```

I tried apt-get update but it gives an error too. So I found out that port 8118 is used by Tor. Tor is not running right now and proxy settings are on automatic. What can I do?

Comment: The mirror might be having problems, see the question I just linked to pick another one.

Comment: See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/155161/58612) to disable the systemwide proxy.

Answer (score -1):

Check your connection. The repository IP could'nt be 127.0.0.1 caus it localhost IP

Comment: That's the proxy address. So the problem is likely with his proxy/VPN.

Comment: Also, the port is 8118.