# Incomplete system-wide proxy settings on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04, networking, proxy, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the system-wide proxy server settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15719/where-are-the-system-wide-proxy-server-settings)

The new:
System Settings>Network>Network proxy

does not allow me to configure the user and password for my proxy, and it is missing the ignore host list feature.

I don't accept "edit /etc/apt/apt.conf" as an answer, this is only to apt.

I want to use the "Apply system wide" feature under the proxy settings, as any normal user should do.

I though Ubuntu was supposed to be user friendly.