# Failed to download repository information Ubuntu 20.04 - Reset?

Tags: grub2, updates

I am having this problem since last update (today) when my system said that there was some updates of Ubuntu's base and other things. I updated, but when I did it I was launched to Login screen, even though my session was still open so I couldn't enter again. I had to reset my PC from hardware button and after that I receive this message when I run Update search app.
The strange thing is that if I click in "accept" when this screen appears I see the screen that says "The sofware is up to date.
I attach this photos, for people who don't know spanish the first one will be the "failed to download..." and the second one will be "all software is up to date"
Also, when I try to change the server and the system asks me to update cache, the windows that shows the progress bar reaches its ends but never closes, never actually ends.

I considered resetting Ubuntu to its factory values (I think it is posible without a USB ISO right?) but I don't know if it will affect Grub and my Dual Boot configuration

I ran sudo apt update, upgrade and clean, Aldo dpkg configure al relatives. It doesn't change.

Comment: perhaps this might help: open a terminal (ctrl+Alt+t) and run `sudo apt update` and thereafter `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [software updater failed to download repository information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297222/software-updater-failed-to-download-repository-information)