# Why am I unable to upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04?

Tags: upgrade

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Toshiba Satellite C55-A and trying to upgrade to 20.04.

Software Updater first gives a "Failed to download repository information" message but I continue on.  My internet connection is fine.  Then I get a notice that third party sources are disabled.  Then I get 404 errors.

I've also tried the upgrade via the terminal and get the same results.

Please help.

This is an edit.

Thanks for the suggestion @Matthew.  This would have done it.

It turns out that the mirror I'd been using for years was not able to handle the upgrade.  This old mirror had at one time been the optimal one for me but something changed along the way.

Hope this info helps somebody and Thank You to you good folks.

Comment: "*Failed to download repository information*" and 404 errors are network or server failures -- try again. "*Third party sources are disabled*" is expected behavior; third-party packages (from third-party sources) are a very common cause of failed upgrades.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [software updater failed to download repository information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297222/software-updater-failed-to-download-repository-information)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, from your description, exactly what is happening in your case; it would be really helpful to get more information about where the process is failing. Open a command terminal.

Before starting, do you have enough free disk space:
`df -h`
Check that enough free space is available for the directory holding the apt files: */var/cache/apt/archives/*

Try removing all unnecessary apt temporary files:
`sudo apt-get autoclean`

Then update the package information from the remote repositories:
`sudo apt update`

Try the upgrade:
`do-release-upgrade`

If you get any useful error output, edit your answer to include the full error details. You may manage to fix the problem yourself by searching on the internet for the error message.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I'm reasonably sure there's plenty of disk space, though I don't know where those particular files are stored.

Comment: OK, the limits on the comments I'm allowed to post don't allow me to properly respond to you.  Thank you anyway.  I'll try a forum elsewhere.

Comment: @Jorge: If you are trying to respond with images or terminal output, can you perhaps edit your question with the relevant information?

Comment: @Jorge - can you please edit your question, detailing any error messages that you are getting in the terminal when you try the commands I have suggested

Answer (score 1):

Check which version of 18.04, 32-bit or 64-bit, you are running. (Go to settings|About). From your machine's specs I suspect it is the 32-bit version.  In that case there is no upgrade to 20.04, which is 64-bit only.  You can continue to use 18.04 which will be supported for two more years or try a different distro.

Comment: Oooohhh!  This had not occurred to me.

Comment: But after checking, it is indeed the 64-bit version.

Comment: Thanks for confirming - checking the specs, the C55-A uses a i5-3230M which definitely supports the x86_64 instruction set.