# Web browsers are not working from GUI but running from terminal with sudo

Tags: command-line, firefox

I am not able to get internet through firefox or any other browser from GUI( as normal user). But when i'm opening firefox from terminal with sudo then internet is working absolutely fine . Talking of internet access i'm able to download any software from Ubuntu Software Centre from GUI.

Comment: Could you start the browser from the terminal, [edit] your question and paste the output?

Comment: @varun What are the outputs of these commands: `ls -l /usr/bin/firefox` and `ls -l /usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a proxy configured in Ubuntu pointing to some server that you don't have access. When running Firefox with another user (like root), the proxy settings are not accessible. Take a look at this question on how to change the proxy: [Where are the system-wide proxy server settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15719/where-are-the-system-wide-proxy-server-settings)