# Running lmgrd on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, package-management

I have installed Xilinx 14.7 in ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine(i386 - 64bit). But I am unable to run lmgrd (for starting the license server).

When I googled this problem, I found that lsb-core package needs to be installed. But the package is having many dependencies, I want to know how to install lsb-core package with all the necessary dependencies. Thanks for the help

On running `sudo apt-get install lsb-core` I got the following output:

```
Package lsb-core is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source 
E: Package 'lsb-core' has no installation candidate
```

So I downloaded `lsb-core` package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/misc/lsb-core site and used `sudo dpkg -i ./lsb-core_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_i386.deb` to install it

By doing it, I got the following output

```
Selecting previously unselected package lsb-core. 
(Reading database ... 163205 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-core_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_i386.deb ... 
Unpacking lsb-core (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ... 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-core: 
lsb-core depends on libc6 (>> 2.3.5). 
lsb-core depends on libz1. 
lsb-core depends on libncurses5. 
lsb-core depends on libpam0g. 
lsb-core depends on lsb-invalid-mta (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) | mail-transport-agent. 
lsb-core depends on at. 
lsb-core depends on binutils. 
lsb-core depends on cron | cron-daemon. 
lsb-core depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev. 
lsb-core depends on locales. 
lsb-core depends on m4. 
lsb-core depends on mailx | mailutils. 
lsb-core depends on ncurses-term. 
lsb-core depends on pax. 
lsb-core depends on psmisc. 
lsb-core depends on alien (>= 8.36). 
lsb-core depends on python3. 
lsb-core depends on lsb-security (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6). 
lsb-core depends on time. 

dpkg: error processing package lsb-core (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lsb-core

I am unable to install gdebi. On running `sudo apt-get install gdebi`
I got the following output: 

 Package gdebi is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is 
 only available from another source  

 E: Package 'gdebi' has no installation candidate

I want to know how to install `lsb-core` package with all the necessary dependencies in one go.
```

Comment: Can you please add the exact output you got after running sudo apt-get install lsb-core?

Comment: Thanks rishi. I have edited the post with the necessary information

Answer (score 0):

Try to install by following method:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lsb/lsb-core_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_i386.deb
sudo gdebi lsb-core_4.1+Debian11ubuntu6_i386.deb
```

Comment: @SumanBhatR you need to run `apt-get -f dist-upgrade` to get the depedencies working

Comment: But apt-get -f dist-upgrade is not working as I don't have proxy authentication. I will be downloading lsb-core package in a windows machine having proxy authentication manually and then transfer it to my ubuntu machine and manually install it. So I would like to know how to download lsb-core package with all its dependencies in one go.

Comment: @SumanBhatR You have to type with sudo like `sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade`

Comment: I am working in a company and they have restricted us from accessing few sites. So even when I used sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade, it gave me the following error:" error 407 proxy authentication required".

Comment: @SumanBhatR check my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/482126/system-wide-proxy-settings-when-on-a-windows-network-with-a-password/482129#482129)

Comment: I have done as you have said, but even now it is giving the same error "proxy authentication failed". Any site starting with "http://mirrors" is blocked in my company and I can't access it with my username and password.

Comment: @SumanBhatR See this answer too http://askubuntu.com/questions/88976/407-proxy-authentication-required/391973#391973 . You have to search about `error 407 proxy authentication required` in googling.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get lsb-core
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Doing the above thing with unrestricted access to Internet solved my problem.