# Couldnot able to install anything

Tags: apt, system-installation, sudo, ping

I tried to use

```
sudo apt-get install
```

its not working.

So I did `ping google.com` it gave me

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

I have net connection and I able to access Internet in browser.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Are you using in your browser a proxy server?

Comment: Yes I am using a proxy server in browser

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15719/where-are-the-system-wide-proxy-server-settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version  do you use? Are you using proxy?

Try digging [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2455972/how-to-fix-your-internet-connection-in-ubuntu-linux.html) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure)

EDIT:

To use apt-get through a proxy, I do the following -

```
sudo apt-get --print-uris install PROGRAM
```

This prints the urls of the packages, so you can download them. For example, using supertux:

```
wilf@comp:~$ sudo apt-get install --print-uris supertux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  supertux-data
The following NEW packages will be installed
  supertux supertux-data
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 59.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 80.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Then download the .deb files from the given links, through a browser that works through the proxy, and you can then install them using Software Centre, or using terminal by this command `cd /FOLDER/WITH/DOWNLOADED-DEB-FILES; dpkg -i *.deb ER cd .... ; gdebi *.deb` . Slow and annoying, but seems to work.

EDIT2 : (Easy Method) (from help.ubuntu.com site)

APT configuration file method

This method uses the apt.conf file which is found in your /etc/apt/ directory. This method is useful if you only want apt-get (and not other applications) to use a http-proxy permanently.

On some installations there will be no apt-conf file set up. This procedure will either edit an existing apt-conf file or create a new apt-conf file.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Add this line to your /etc/apt/apt.conf file (substitute your details for yourproxyaddress and proxyport).

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

Save the apt.conf file.

If your proxy needs a login/password, substitute:

```
"http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

with

```
"http://username:password@yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

Something like following should work fine

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://lgn:pwd@192.168.1.254:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "http://lgn:pwd@192.168.1.254:8080/"
```

Comment: I use 14.04 ubuntu
I am using proxy in broswer.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: It is better to configure a proxy server for APT or system-wide.

Comment: I edited again :)

Comment: Thanks everyone...
It worked..
I edited /etc/apt/apt.conf and /etc/environment